# how to open form in same page like a popup using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

by using the following code iam getting form as splitted into multiple tabs, i want it as single form opened like a popup

```
$(function () {
      $('a.linkId').click(function () {
           $.get(this.href, function (result) {
             $(result).dialog({draggable: false,modal:true});
           });

           return false;
      });
});
```

am using mvc,
this is view code for my controller

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.studentID }, new { @class="linkId"}) |
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)